# object and file upload fields are not showing

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

here is my schema But ingredients object with its fields name and amount is not showing and also my image upload filed is not showing.So can you tell me my mistake and how to correct it?

```
Recipes.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Recipe Name",
        max: 100
    },

        ingredients: {
            type: Object,
            label:"Ingredients",
            minCount: 1
        },

    "ingredients.$.name": {
    type: String
        },
    "ingredients.$.amount": {
    type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "How to prepare ",
    },
    time: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Time (Minutes)",
    },
    image: {
        type: String,

        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: 'fileUpload',
                collection: 'RecipesImages',
                label: 'Recipe Picture'
            }
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    }
}));
```

and here i am putting them with auto-form in my template

```
{{#autoForm collection="Recipes" id="insertRecipes" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a Recipe</legend>
        {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='Ingredients'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='Ingredients.name'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='Ingredients.amount'}}



        {{> afQuickField name='description' rows=6}}
        {{> afQuickField name='time'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='image'}}

    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Recipe</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the schema is not defined properly. If you want to make the `ingredients` property an array of objects you need to define the `type` as an array, like so:

```
ingredients: {
    type: [Object],
    label:"Ingredients",
    minCount: 1
}
```

Then, in your template you have the name of the property using upper case I, instead of lower case, as it's defined in the schema. Change the name to `ingredients`

```
{{> afQuickField name='ingredients'}}
```

You don't need to include the sub properties of `ingredients` in your template. Autoform will automatically create the UI for sub properties of an array of objects.

For the file upload, the input type has to match the definition within your schema. Try changing the field definition in your template to:

```
{{> afFieldInput name='image'}}
```